# Force The Location Of A Gtk4 Window On A Wayland WM

Tags: rust, gtk, window-managers, wayland, gtk4

I'm driving myself nuts with this... I want to create a power menu using the Gtk4 framework in rust and I can't seem to crack the window positioning. I want my window to be positioned at a specific location whenever it's opened. Doing some research, it seems like gtk3 had a way of implementing this, but it's been deprecated in Gtk4. I've also read that you can request the location change by sending a message to the Wayland compositor, but I can't seem to figure that out either.

Looking for some guidance from a more experienced programmer than myself. Not sure where to go with this but I'm determined to learn and make it work. I just feel like my migraines are getting to intense from hitting my head on my desk all day.

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm currently working on Hyprland as my WM.

I've tried using wayland-client from crates.io to send messages to the Wayland compositor, but the more documentation I read on the Wayland protocol the more I want to throw my laptop off of the empire state building...

Even reading through the Wayland documentation, it doesn't seem to document a message I can send to the compositor to request the window be moved/placed at a specific position within the environment. It's also highly likely that I misread the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In Wayland, the composer (mutter/clutter in Gnome) controls the window position, not the graphics library (GTK) itself.

To interact with the composer it will be necessary to create something along the lines of a gnome shell extension. I'll leave here the link to an [extension](https://github.com/sunwxg/gnome-shell-extension-arrangeWindows/blob/master/arrangeWindows%40sun.wxg%40gmail.com/extension.js) that manipulates windows as a code redeference.